# Plot a data frame as a table

Tags: r, plot

I am moving away from Word/Excel tables and trying to generate a table in **R**. I have a data frame that I'd like to simply print as a plot, while being able to shade/colour cells and generally play with the aesthetics.

```
x <- data.frame(row.names=paste("Name",1:10))
x[,1] <- 1:10
x[,2] <- sample(1:100,10)
x[,3] <- sample(LETTERS[1:26],10)
colnames(x) <- c("Value 1", "Value 2", "Label")
```

`View(x)` provides the exact format I'd like my table, just as a save-able plot.

I tried

```
plot(x,type="h")
```

But received an error:

> Error in plot.default(...) :  formal argument "type" matched by
>   multiple actual arguments

I have seen how to output tables with two columns, but how can I plot the data frame as-is? Bonus points for showing how to stick that table below another scatter plot that I have created, so that the output ggsave has the scatter plot with the table under it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since I am going for the bonus points:

```
   #Plot your table with table Grob in the library(gridExtra)
   ss <- tableGrob(x)

   #Make a scatterplot of your data
   k <- ggplot(x,aes(x=x$"Value 1",y=x$"Value 2")) + 
   geom_point()

   #Arrange them as you want with grid.arrange
   grid.arrange(k,ss)
```

You can change the number of rows, columns, height and so on if you need to.

Good luck with it
[image]

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/gridExtra.pdf

Comment: wow that simple? awesome thanks mate! Bonus points awarded! Do you happen to have an answer to my additional question in comments to Robert's answer perchance?

Comment: In the tables that we showed there is no cut off in the word Name 1 as far as I can see so how do you mean? 
Also, this could be due to the row.names that you use. When you just give a new column for the Names 1-10 it would probably be okay.

Comment: install.packages(gridExtra)
Error in install.packages(gridExtra) : object 'gridExtra' not found ... Don´t know, if it is still a library?

Comment: Make sure you have gridExtra between quotations install.packages("gridExtra")

Answer (score 21):

Try this. Yes use `pdf()` to plot a PDF file (e.g. `mydf.pdf`) or `png()` to plot a png file:

```
library(gridExtra)
pdf("mypdf.pdf", height=6, width=4)
grid.table(x)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks again, edited this comment to say tthat the strings in the rownames (e.g. Name 1" in my example) are being cut off, regardless of where I string wrap them, any ideas?

Comment: I've used instead table.grob which solves this issue, and allows me to use grid.arrange late, thanks again all!